# How to use List<Tuple<long,long>>[] in C#?

Tags: c#, graph-theory

i have a method like this:

edges are like this

4 this is node Count

1 2 1 the first two value are vertices,and the third element is weight of the edges

4 1 2

2 3 2

1 3 5

```
public static List<Tuple<long,long>>[] WeightedGraph(long NodeCount,long[][] edges)
{
    List<Tuple<long, long>>[] Weightedgraph = new List<Tuple<long, long>>[NodeCount + 1];
    for(int i=0; i<Weightedgraph.Length;i++)
    {
        Weightedgraph[i] = new List<Tuple<long, long>>();
    }
    foreach(var vertex in edges)
    {
        **Weightedgraph[vertex[0]].Add();**
    }
}
```

how can i complete the ** part?

Comment: Just an example `Weightedgraph[0].Add(new Tuple(1, 2));`

Comment: what you are expecting to add to `Weightedgraph[vertex[0]]`

Comment: the first one is always the start node and i implement it with a List<Tuple<long, long>>[] where the indexes of the array showing the start nodes and the 2 other properties will be added into the list of tupple<long,long> item 1 is another node and item 2 is weight.

Comment: If you want to use the edges info later, I would suggest doing `.ToLookup()`, so that you can easily acces all edges of given vertex

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use [`Tuple.Create(long, long)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple.create?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
public static List<Tuple<long, long>>[] WeightedGraph(long NodeCount, long[][] edges)
{
    List<Tuple<long, long>>[] weightedgraph = new List<Tuple<long, long>>[NodeCount + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < weightedgraph.Length; i++)
    {
        weightedgraph[i] = new List<Tuple<long, long>>();
    }

    foreach (var vertex in edges)
    {
        weightedgraph[vertex[0]].Add(Tuple.Create(1L, 2L));
    }

    return weightedgraph;
}
```

However note that for C# version 7 or later you can use [the `(x, y)` "value tuple" syntax](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/) to simplify things and to provide more meaningful names for the tuple elements.

In the example below, I've modified your code to call the tuple elements X and Y:

```
public static List<(long X, long Y)>[] WeightedGraph(long nodeCount, long[][] edges)
{
    var weightedgraph = new List<(long X, long Y)>[nodeCount + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < weightedgraph.Length; i++)
    {
        weightedgraph[i] = new List<(long X, long Y)>();
    }

    foreach (var vertex in edges)
    {
        weightedgraph[vertex[0]].Add((1L, 2L));
    }

    return weightedgraph;
}
```

Comment: I believe you should mention that it's known as *Value Tuple* and available from C#7

Answer (score 1):

Let's add *readability* (which index means what):

```
// I've changed NodeCount into int: 
// do you really want a graph with more than 2e9 vertexes?
public static List<Tuple<long,long>>[] WeightedGraph(int NodeCount, long[][] edges) {
  //TODO: validate NodeCount and edges

  // Naming: "WeightedGraph" is the method's name; "result" is what we return 
  // Initialization: we want
  List<Tuple<long, long>>[] result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, NodeCount)                            // NodeCount vertexes
    .Select(node => new List<Tuple<long, long>>())  //   Each has a List<T> of edges
    .ToArray();                                     // Organized as an array

  foreach (var edge in edges) {
    // Let's add readability end decrypt edges format
    int vertexFrom = (int) (edge[0]);
    long vertexTo = edge[1];
    long edgeWeight = edge[2];

    result[vertexFrom].Add(Tuple.Create(vertexTo, edgeWeight)); 
  }  

  return result;
}
```